# Rails Try Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

My models are Ticket, Staff, Post.

Ticket belongs_to Staff
Staff has_many Posts

I have The Ticket instance @ticket.
I would like to render all posts related with the ticket.
If there are no the related posts "No posts available" message will be shown.
My version is quite verbose:

```
if @ticket.staff and @ticket.staff.posts
  render @ticket.staff.posts
else 
  There are no answers available
```

But I would like to do it something more neatly.

```
= render(@ticket.staff.try(:post).any?) || "There are no answers available"
```

It gives me an error **'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ticket model you can 'delegate'

```
delegate :posts, to: :staff, allow_nil: true
```

In the controller make an instance variable.

```
@posts = ticket.posts
```

And in your view

```
-if @post.present?
  =render @posts
-else
  There are no answers available
```

Comment: Don't You think it's more verbose than my version?

Comment: Well to me, in rails it is about readability. And sometimes readability means less verbose but in this case, it means obey law of demeter, puts view elements in view only, controller elements in controller, etc. In the end, it is simpler in the views, with just that code. And you will probably use ticket.posts elsewhere, so it make your entire project less verbose later on.